# AngularJS $scope.push not updating the view from a $http data response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I’m performing a `$http` request to the 500px API for a set of popular photos. The response object is being returned successfully, and I’m having trouble pushing the returned photo items to the view.

My controller code looks like this:

```
meanApp.controller 'SearchController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Global', ($scope, $http, Global) ->

  $scope.global = Global
  $scope.photos = []

  $scope.submit = ->
    if $scope.text

      $http.get("https://api.500px.com/v1/photos?feature=popular").success (data) ->
        $scope.photos.push data

]
```

The response object (as JSON) looks like this (trimmed down for brevity):

```
{
  "current_page":1,
  "total_pages":1449,
  "total_items":7244,
  "photos":[
    {
      "id":58494612,
      "user_id":1795149,
      "name":"Van Gogh!!!!"
    },
    {
      "id":49566952,
      "user_id":1795149,
      "name":"Autumn touch!"
    },
    {
      "id":49527034,
      "user_id":2670757,
      "name":"Untitled"
    },
    {
      "id":39374598,
      "user_id":3669660,
      "name":"The Wild Cannot Be Tamed Nor The Rednecks in it! "
    },
    {
      "id":28303657,
      "user_id":2843749,
      "name":"Main road to go to the moon"
    }
  ]
}
```

My view looks like this:

```
<h1>Photo search</h1>

<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="SearchController">
Enter text and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="photo in photos.photos">{{photo.name}}</li>
  <li ng-hide="photos.length">No photos</li>
</ul>
```

The current behaviour is that the `<ul>` does not update. The expected behaviour is for the `photo` items to push to the `<li>`s. I have read about potentially needing to use `$apply`, but this hasn't given me any luck either.

Comment: Try `$scope.photos.push data.data`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to do it, and `console.log(data.data)` is giving me `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

The problem is that your `ng-repeat` is outside of the scope of `SearchController`

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="SearchController">
Enter text and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form> <!-- end SearchController -->

<ul>
  <!-- Outside of SearchController's scope -->
  <li ng-repeat="photo in photos.photos">{{photo.name}}</li> 
  <li ng-hide="photos.length">No photos</li>
</ul>
```

so it doesn't have access to the value of `photos.photos`.

As a solution, you can wrap your entire "Photo search" section, including the search and the results, under the scope of one controller.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/789ijb05ufOO4mLIMEgQ?p=preview)

You will probably also have to consider my previous response ...

#### Previous response

It seems that following the response to your request, by pushing the results to `$scope.photos` as an array, its contents might look like:

```
[{ current_page: ..., photos: [...], total_items: ..., totalpages: ...}]
```

If that's the case, you need to access it with an expression that looks like:

```
<li ng-repeat="photo in photos[0].photos">
```

Perhaps though you're really meaning to assign data to `$scope.photos` like

```
$scope.photos = data
```

In this case, your expression might work as you currently have it.

Comment: I didn't have any luck trying your suggestions (in a combination of both too). Could it be related to the fact that each photo in `photos: [...]` has an index?

Comment: I thought photos: [] was an array. Sounds like it's an object with numeric keys? Can you replace the abbreviated response in your question with a full JSON output?

Comment: Looks like I’ve confused myself a bit here. I've run `console.log(angular.toJson(data))` and have updated the response from that above.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your response is available for use as a Javascript object.
Try to

```
console.log(data);
console.log($scope.photos);
```

in the success function of your $http.get, and see if **data** is a JavaScript object or an array of objects (in the browser's JS Console). If its displayed as a string, you need to JSON parse the response using

```
JSON.parse(response);
```

before pushing to the array. Note that the thing you are pushing to the $scope.photos array has to be a photo object. console.log($scope.photos) should show an **array** of **objects**. Finally, after pushing data, you need to run

```
$scope.apply();
```